# How to capture time for several times with one QR code (PHP)

Tags: php, datetime, qr-code

Currently I'm having a problem with capturing time using QR code.
The QR stores the information of booking number and its ID.
There are T1, T2, and T3 which denote as T1 for the first time capture, T2 for the second while T3 for the third time to capture the time.
So basically, the user would scan three times with the same qr code.
For now, I only able to capture the T1 but not for the other two.
So the columns in database should be "id, bookingNumber, T1, T2, T3".
Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$db = new Db(); 
$action = $_REQUEST["action"];

    switch($action){
    case "insert_info":
        $id = $_REQUEST["id"];
        $bookingNumber = $_REQUEST["bookingNumber"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO record (id, bookingNumber, T1) VALUES ('$id', '$bookingNumber', NOW())";
        $result = $db->query($query);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "Successfully scanned.",
        "result" => $result
       ));
    break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should have the record table set up correctly in the first place or add another table.

Comment: Yes, the record table is set up correctly with the columns "id, bookingNumber, T1, T2, T3".
T2 and T3 are hoped to be captured for the second and third scan of qr code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if T1 / T2 fields are already has a value before inserting.
Something like this:

```
        $query = "SELECT T1, T2, T3 FROM record WHERE id =" . $id .";"
```

Then you should check the case when T3 is already filled with value - then you should send an error response (as it seems that user scanned the 4th time).

In case if T2 is not empty - make insertion of current time to T3 field, etc.

Comment: I've tried to code it out. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, you've got the concept, but you have to debug the code carefully.
A few tips for you:
1. while statement is not necessary - I assume that id should be unique so that means you'll have only 1 array element OR false here:
`$row_sql=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sql)`
2. $T1 and other will always be equal to empty string as you assign the values to other variables - $Ta, $Tb, $Tc